# Load an .fbx object any time during the game with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a Minecraft-like game with normal physics (ice cubes slip on the floor when you push them for example) in C# with Unity.

Right now I'm trying to destroy a glass cube when it's been hit.
I already have the .fbx (animation of the cube exploding created with Blender) which works fine when I drag it on the scene and play it, but I want to play it only it at a certain time.
It's not just an animation. It has objects inside the .fbx

My glass cube is a GameObject. I have a class GenMap (MonoBehaviour) and I read a config file to know the positions of the cube and the kind of cube (dirt/ice/glass/stone).

If it's a glass cube I add a component which is a breakable class in another .cs.

In this class I have an OnCollisionEnter function to destroy my cube and play the animation.

My problem is that I don't know how to get my .fbx at this moment.

I tried a public Transform object and dragged my .fbx into Unity but since I use addComponent("Breakable") my public variable is null on my object when it's been generated.
I understand that when I addcomponent I attach the .cs but not the public variable I assigned manually

```
void AttachTextureToObject(GameObject obj, int type) //Assign a texture to an object
{
    _meshrenderer = obj.GetComponent("MeshRenderer") as MeshRenderer;
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1:
            _meshrenderer.material.mainTexture = textureG; //textureGrass i initialised in a special function
            break;
        case 2:
            _meshrenderer.material.mainTexture = textureD;
            break;
        case 3:
            _meshrenderer.material.mainTexture = textureS;
            break;
        case 4:
            _meshrenderer.material.mainTexture = textureW;
            break;
        case 5 :
            _meshrenderer.material.mainTexture = textureI;
            obj.collider.sharedMaterial = materialI;
            break;
        case 10: //glass type
            obj.AddComponent("SurfaceReflection"); //add a shader to get glass "texture"
            obj.AddComponent("Breakable"); //add my class breakable
            obj.renderer.material.shader = shaderG;
            obj.collider.sharedMaterial = materialI;
            break;
    }
}
```

//different .cs

```
public class Breakable : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Transform breaking_cube; //when i hit play the .sc attached to my gameobject is null and if i drag my .fbx  manually and hit my cube i see the animation
    Transform current_cube;

    bool broke = false;

    void Start() //when i addComponent i initialize the current cube to itself
    {
        current_cube = this.transform;
        breaking_cube = Resources.Load("Blender/broken_cube") as Transform; //this doesn't work 
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
        {
            broke = true;
            Destroy(current_cube);
            Transform broken_cube = Instantiate(breaking_cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
            current_cube = broken_cube;
            if (broke)
            {
                if (!current_cube.transform.animation.isPlaying)
                {
                    //i will destroy my gameobject when i finish
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to addcomponent an animation and add my .fbx but since it's not just an animation, it doesn't work either.

I started working with Unity recently so I probably missed or misused a function.
I don't know if I'm clear enough but if you need a screenshot or something, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a prefab of your Cube.

(Once in the scene, drag the gameobject back into the project hierarchy and it will become a prefab).

Now, any time you need to you can Instantiate a copy of the prefab:

```
public Transform CubePrefab;

void Start() 
{
  GameObject cube = (GameObject)Instantiate(CubePrefab, new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Quaternion.identity);
  AttachTextureToObject(cube, 10/*glass*/);
}
```

Refer to [Instantiating Prefabs at runtime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time

I tried what you said few differents ways but i always have the same problem.

When i create my Gameobject, if it's a glass cube, i do 
obj.addComponent("breakable") // i attach the script to my object
and when i do that my public variable which was initialize with my prefab become null.

Comment: I added your AttachTextureToObject() call above. is that how you called it?

Comment: No.

I have a GenMap class attach on an emptyObject

when i hit play

i load a file 

0 0 0 10 //glass cube at pos x=0 y=0 z=0
1 0 0 1
...

i create a Gameobject a theses positions and call AttachTextureToObject(the gameObject i created, 10)

when i arrive at case 10
i addComponent("Breakable") wich is a .cs

i linked my breakable.cs script

if you wand i can link my genmap.cs

Comment: Try the method above, using the prefab of your cube and then attaching the components to the instantiated copy. That should work. You can't load FBX's at runtime, you need to load them at compile time.

Comment: you mean drag it at playtime ?
It work but i want it to be automatic
Will it be if when it's compile ?